# ReturnToSourceQueue tool of NServicebus is not working

Tags: nservicebus

I have several messages (pub/sub) in the error queue. When I use the ReturnToSourceQueue tool it says that all message are handled successful but when I look in the error queues the messages are still there and the event handlers are not triggered. I'm using NServiceBus 4.3.3 with sql server. I have disabled the timeoutmanager and not using second level retries. Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It was the same reason as the problem I had with second level retry. I had to disable the saga feature and then I could remove the disabling of the time out manager. After that everything works :-)